# Kendo Grid Custom template not working in new version (2014.3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid setup like this

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
.Name("projects")
.Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.ID).Width(90);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Name).Width(300);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Description);
        columns.Bound(c => c.ProjectCode);
        columns.Template(c => "").ClientTemplate(Html.ActionLink("Tasks", "TasksList", "Task", new { projectId = "#=ID#" }, new { @class = "k-button k-button-medium-grid" }).ToHtmlString()).Width(65);

    })
)
```

This set up with the Client Template (for the last column) was working fine until I updated to the new version of Kendo (2014.3.1119)
Now i get an error on the page "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'context' of null". 
Has anyone else bumped into this problem? Did the syntax change and now setting up the client template like this no longer works?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use template and clientTemplate methods to the same column. If you are using field id just bind second column to this field:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
.Name("projects")
.Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.ID).Width(90);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Name).Width(300);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Description);
        columns.Bound(c => c.ProjectCode);
        columns.Bound(c => c.ID).ClientTemplate(Html.ActionLink("Tasks", "TasksList", "Task", new { projectId = "#=ID#" }, new { @class = "k-button k-button-medium-grid" }).ToHtmlString()).Width(65);

    })
)
```

You can read more about Kendo MVC column templates in [Kendo Grid FAQ](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-do-i-customize-the-way-a-property-is-displayed-in-a-grid-bound-column).